# Jersy IllegalArgumentException jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader exception thrown with JDK17 and tomcat 9

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, servlet-3.0, tomcat9, openjdk-17

I am upgrading servlet based web application from JDK1.8 to openjdk17. after updating the jdk and supported with java module info. Tomcat9 failed to run the web application. I tried with different repackage version but the results are same. I cannot move to tomcat 10 which supported by jersy 2.26 and updated version.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Servlet.init() for servlet [Fesfes] threw exception
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:171)
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:425)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:915)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:869)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:775)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1206)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1178)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1174)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:345)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1143)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1096)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fes.fes</groupId>
    <artifactId>dsda</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>dsda</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi-resource-locator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance-repackaged</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>             
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>             
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>             
            <version>5.0</version>         
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.69</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.69</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.69</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>target</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <useCache>false</useCache>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

module-info.java

```
module com.fes.fes{
    requires java.base;
    requires javax.servlet.api;
    requires javax.ws.rs.api;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires org.bouncycastle.provider;
    requires org.bouncycastle.pkix;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.core;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires com.rabbitmq.client;
}
```

Comment: when I change the source/binary format to jdk9. its work fine. As I change to JDK10 or higher same exception occur.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz yes this issue is similar. Jersey 2.26 not support higher the JKD9.